# How to count number of groups that meet a certain condition with MongoDB aggregate framework?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, node-mongodb-native

I have a MongoDB aggregation operation that uses a couple of groups:

```
{ $group: { "_id": { "vid": "$visitor_id", "pid":"$project.id" } } }
{ $group: { "_id": "$_id.vid", "count": { $sum: 1} } }
```

that returns the following data:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "_id": "user1",
      "count": 1
    }, 
    {
      "_id": "user2",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "user3",
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

How could I go about returning the total number of users with more than 1 project (`count` field). In this case it would be something like:

```
{
  total: 1
}
```

because only `user2` has more than 1 project (`count` > 1).

I've tried adding the following group operation to no avail:

```
{ 
  $group: { 
    "_id": null, 
    count: {
      $sum: {$cond: [{$gt: ['$_id.count', 1]}, 1, 0]}
    } 
  } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just have a final aggregation pipeline step as the **`$match`** operator to filter out the counts i.e. `{ "$match": {"count": {"$gt": 1}}}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result as simple as adding the following three aggregation stages into your pipeline:

```
{$match: {count: {$gt: 1}}}
{$group: {_id: null, total: {$sum: 1}}}
{$project: {_id: 0, total: 1}}
```

1. As [chridam mentined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35727021/how-to-count-number-of-groups-that-meet-a-certain-condition-with-mongodb-aggrega/35727336#comment59129193_35727021) you can have a **`$match`** stage to filter all the users that have more than 1 projects.
2. Then use another **`$group`** stage to count the total number of such users.
3. The third step is just cosmetics, leaves only the `total` field.

Comment: Absolutely right. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks a lot to both you and @chridam for the help!

Comment: That's because the `$group` stage is such a cool thing you want to put all into it :) Glad it worked!